# Alpine Update to icu-libs Causing Dependency Conflicts

Tags: docker, dependencies, postgis, alpine-linux

```
[91mERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

icu-libs-64.2-r0:
    conflicts: icu-libs-62.1-r0
    satisfies: xerces-c-3.2.2-r2[so:libicuuc.so.64]
  icu-libs-62.1-r0:
    conflicts: icu-libs-64.2-r0
    satisfies: .postgresql-rundeps-0[so:libicui18n.so.62]
               .postgresql-rundeps-0[so:libicuuc.so.62
```

My build has started failing after a year of no issue due to this conflict with icu-libs after it updated on alpine's `community` channel. The only APK repos I have added are

```
--repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
--repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
--repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
```

I would revert to 3.9 but libgeos, proj, and gdal are only available on edge, which I need for this build.

Sorry if this question is naive but there any way to have apk add both versions? I've been trying to pick apart the `mdillon/postgis` image that's available on dockerhub since I can't cache unofficial images but it won't build and results in the same error no matter what.

I've been upping postgres versions and no dice.

Comment: What do you have in your /etc/apk/repositories? This kind of issues often comes as a result of mixing edge with stable branches.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason alpine decided to explicitly add the icu package version to the icu-depends-dev, instead of just saying depends on icu package.

From the git repo for icu:
depends_dev="$pkgname=$pkgver-r$pkgrel"

That means any package you are running in your build environment
that required icu-dev to build, now in turn requires a specific version of the icu package.

The only way to get around is to remove any packages in your build environment that required icu-dev to build.

At the end of the day I am not sure why they would not just have done

depends_dev="$pkgname"